# Distribution of 4 distinct balls into 5 identical boxes without any restrictions, order of the balls is important

Tags: combinatorics

> Find number of ways $4$ distinct balls can be distributed into $5$ identical
>   boxes where any box can contain any number of balls (even empty boxes are allowed)
>
> Note that the order of balls inside a box is important (i.e., arrangements can be considered different if order of the balls inside a box changes)
>
> (source: This problem is created by myself by modifying [this question](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=3134#top) from careerbless)

Without the second part "order of balls are important", I can solve the question as per the information obtained from the linked site. Then, answer is $15$. and it can be solved using  Stirling numbers (solution 1), Bell numbers(solution 2) or with basic permutation and combination concepts(solution 3) or listing out the possibilities (solution 4). [see the link].

Now, take the entire question and add the constraint - "the order of balls inside a box is important". How to approach this problem?

I just need directions towards solving this so that I can work on it and find solutions myself. Please also tell if the same concepts (Stirling numbers, Bell numbers and basic permutation and combination concepts) can be applied then.

Comment: Cases for one empty box, more cases for two empty boxes, more...

Comment: @Muralidharan: OP has specified that  ".... the order of balls inside a box is important ..."

Comment: The general case of $n$ distinct balls and $r$ identical boxes can be solved in this way: The number of non empty boxes can be $1,2,\ldots, r$. Arrange the $n$ balls in $n!$ ways. If there are $k$ non empty boxes, then we introduce $k-1$ separators and get the number of placements as $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$\times n!$ But of these shuffling the identical boxes in $k$ ways, we have counted each arrangement $k$ times. Thus for $k$ non empty boxes, the number of ways is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}$. Now the required number of placements is $\sum_{k=1}^r \binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case by case works well here (as the numbers are so small).  Not immediately clear to me how to generalize to get a simple closed formula for generalizations.

Here are the ways to partition $4$:

$$\{4\},\;\{3,1\},\;\{2,2\},\;\{2,1,1\},\;\{1,1,1,1\}$$

As order matters, we proceed case by case:

$\{4\}$:  there are $4!=\fbox {24}$ cases.

$\{3,1\}$:  there are $4$ ways to pick the singleton, and $3!=6$ ways to order the triple so  again $\fbox {24}$ cases.

$\{2,2\}$:  there are $3$ ways to pick the pairs (just decide which ball is paired with  ball $\#1$).  There are $2$ ways to order each pair hence $3\times 2\times 2=\fbox {12}$ cases.

$\{2,1,1\}$:  there are $\binom 42=6$ ways to choose the pair and $2$ ways to order it, hence $6\times 2 =\fbox {12}$ cases.

$\{1,1,1,1\}$:  there are no options here, so $\fbox {1}$ cases.

Combining we get $$24+24+12+12+1= \fbox {73}$$

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the partitions, e.g. for $4$, you could mechanically use the formula:

*(multinomial coeff.)$\times$ (permutations within boxes)$\div$ (permutations of indistinguishable boxes)*

$\{4\}:\;\binom44 \times 4! = 24$

$\{3,1\}:\;\binom4{3,1}\times 3! = 24$

$\{2,2\}:\;\binom4{2,2}\times2!2! \div 2!= 12$

$\{2,1,1\}:\;\binom4{2,1,1}\times 2! \div2!=12$

$\{1,1,1,1\}:\;\binom4{1,1,1,1}\div4! = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Chancing on this question, here's a direct formula using **Lah numbers** (though summation can't be avoided.)

with $n$  denoting distinct balls and $k$ denoting identical boxes,

$L(n,k) = \binom{n}{k}^{n-1}P_{n-k}$

and the formula for permutations with some boxes empty is
$$\sum_{j=1}^kL(n,j)$$

With $n=4\;$ and $k=5$ it works out to

$^4C_1\,^3P3 + ^4C_2\,^3P_2 +^4C_3\,^3P_1 +^4C_4\,^3P_0$

$= 4(3*2*1) + 6(3*2) + 4(3) +1 = 73$